# Magento Tier Price on Category view is different from Product view

Tags: magento

We have a store with two different currencies: Euro (multiple sites) & Pound Sterling (only one website).
We have trouble with displaying the correct tier prices on the category page of the UK store.

We have setup Tier prices as follows:

- All sites | [EUR] | 3 and higer | 7.50
- All sites | [EUR] | 5 and higer | 7.25
- All sites | [EUR] | 10 and higer | 7.00
- All sites | [EUR] | 18 and higer | 6.75
- UK site | [GBP] | 3 and higer | 7.50
- UK site | [GBP] | 5 and higer | 7.25
- UK site | [GBP] | 10 and higer | 7.00
- UK site | [GBP] | 18 and higer | 6.75

The problem is that for some reason magento shows the wrong Tier prices on category view UK. On the product page the Tier prices for UK are correct.

For example: 6.75, is shown on category view as low as: 4.82. On the product page it's 6.75 again (the correct price).

My guess is that magento captures the [EUR] prices, recalculates them to [GBP] and shows these prices in the category view for the UK store.

How can I fix this without having to set Tier prices for each individual store view for [EUR], and have magento use the [GBP] prices for the UK store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out our solution:

Under System / Manager Currencies / Value

The exchange rate was set lower for GBP. So instead of 1.0000 it was 0.7450.
This results in Magento recalulating the prices on the category pages.

We've set this back to 1.0000 and disabled the automatic update.
Now the prices are displaying correctly again.

Answer (score 0):

Try clean cache and make reindex data via admin end: **System -> Index Management** and **System -> Cache Management**

Comment: Tried that several times, even with cache disabled completely. Problem is that Magento chooses to use the [EUR] prices which are set to all websites, and doesn't choose the store views prices [GBP].

Comment: May be in category template you get default price, without store id?